# Is there a difference between adjectives which have their corresponding adverbs listed in the dictionary, and those that don't?

Tags: adverbs, dictionaries

Sometimes, some authoritative dictionaries give us the adverb below its adjective, but sometimes, for instance *penitential*, there is no other adverb given.

However, it seems like we need only to add -ly and penitential has its adverb: penitentially. What is the difference between adjectives where the  adverb is listed and the ones where it exists, but is not listed?

(ps: I read carefully about the discussion below, actually, it is a question that most Chinese Engligh learners cannot or rarely use stance adverbs or adverb of manner that however, are often used by native speaker. In this case, if a Chinese English learner want to use stance adverbs or adverb of manner, for example, he is mentally ill, comprehensively analyze, how dose s/he know which word has a verb form, and that is why I mentioned dictionaries, which can show us the source)

Comment: No, not  every adjective has its adverb. You can't do something _bluely_, for example.

Comment: I CV'd because I think that this belongs on Meta ELL (if anywhere). It seems to ask about conventions used in dictionaries, and questions about using English-learning resources (such as dictionaries) generally belong on Meta, not here.

Comment: I do not think this should be closed. Just because the OP mentions dictionaries doesn't mean the question is only about them.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I don't think it is about dictionary conventions... I think it is about whether there is a grammatical reason that a dictionary lists adverbs for some adjectives and omits others even though they exist. I don't think it belongs on Meta, because if it were strictly about dictionary conventions it would be answerable by general reference, i.e. finding where the dictionary explains its conventions.

Comment: @ColleenV I think that it wasn't very clear before, but your edit (e.g., the extra wording you added in the last sentence) helps to make that point. (Thanks for editing!) However, I'm still not entirely convinced, because [some dictionaries](https://onelook.com/?w=penitentially&ls=a) do list "penitentially" as an adverb. I therefore still think that this might be a difference among dictionaries rather than a difference among words.

Comment: @ColleenV If it is a difference among words, then the only difference I can think of is that some words are more "obscure" than others (as alphabet says in his/her answer), but there's not much English-learning in that fact. I'm still willing to be convinced, though.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan We sometimes close questions that result from typos because they're of limited usefulness, but I think this is a question that other learners might wonder about even if the answer is "It's just about how common the adverbs are, and here's some advice for determining if there is an adverb for that adjective" (or different dictionaries handle this differently) so we should attempt to answer it. Just know that there isn't a pattern or rule there could be helpful.

Comment: @ColleenV If the question were simply "how can I tell whether an adjective has a corresponding adverbial form", then I'd certainly consider it appropriate here. I'm deferring to the opinion of my "site elders" and retracting my close vote, but I'd still prefer if OP made clearer that this question is not about editorial practices of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Some dictionaries, like [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/penitential), do list a form "penitentially." In general, with more obscure adjectives, you often can create an adverb by adding "-ly" even if the dictionary does not list them explicitly, at least if they end in a suffix like "-ial" to which "-ly" is often appended.

However, many more common adjectives do not have corresponding adverbs: *fun*, *kindred*, *silken*, and many others.

Comment: I hate to nitpick but [silkenly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silkenly) is in Merriam-Webster. They also have [bluely](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bluely) but I'd use it in the sense "having the blues" or depressedly rather than of the colour.